# Arduino Code hang

Tags: arduino-mega, led, bluetooth, rtc

I am working on a project to dim/brighten the LED lights between each hour. To make the program readable i have only kept the code for few hours.

For example if T1 is at 255 PWM and T2 is 20 PWM, the code calculates the moves required to dim the LED by One PWM every few second such that by T2 the PWM is at 20.

I have Included DS1307 RTC for keeping track of time, further i have used a HC-05 Bluetooth module to communicate with the Arduino, using Android phone, so that i can change the PWM values between T1 and T2.

When i run the code it works perfectly for some time post which it freezes, and the LED starts flickering.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
String fromAndroid;
////////RTC
int h = 0;
int m = 0;

int hours;
unsigned long interval = 1000;

////////////Millis
unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long White_previousMillis;
unsigned long previousMillis;//for clock
unsigned long Hr_interval = 3600000;
unsigned long white_each_interval;

int pwm02 = 2;
int pwm03 = 3;
int pwm04 = 4;
int pwm05 = 5;
int pwm06 = 6;
int pwm07 = 7;

/////////////////Peak Keeper
int white_t24 = 10;
int white_t1 = 233;
int white_t2 = 18;
int white_t3 = 189;
int white_t4 = 12;
int white_t5 = 255;
int white_t6 = 19;
int white_t7 = 199;
int white_t8 = 2;
int white_t9 = 177;
int white_t10 = 2;
int white_t11 = 245;
int white_t12 = 12;
int white_t13 = 252;
int white_t14 = 0;
int white_t15 = 255;
int white_t16 = 50;
int white_t17 = 239;
int white_t18 = 20;
int white_t19 = 253;
int white_t20 = 1;
int white_t21 = 252;
int white_t22 = 2;
int white_t23 = 255;


/////Secondary time
int white_Secondary;

int white_steps; //new

int white_move; //New

RTC_DS1307 rtc;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  rtc.begin();
  if (! rtc.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while (1);
  }
  if (! rtc.isrunning())
  {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
  }
  Serial.println("Start");
  //  rtc.adjust(DateTime(2017,12,17,11,52,00));
  pinMode(pwm02, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() == 0)
  {
    DateTime now = rtc.now();
    currentMillis = millis();
    hours = now.hour();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval)
    {
      Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
      Serial.print('/');
      Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
      Serial.print('/');
      Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
      Serial.print(" (");
      Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
      Serial.print(':');
      Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
      Serial.print(':');
      Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
      Serial.println(')');
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
    }

    if (hours == 12)
    {
      if(now.minute()==00 && now.second()<=1)
      {
        white_Secondary = white_t24;
        analogWrite(pwm02, white_Secondary);
      }
      white_steps = white_t1 - white_t24;
      if (white_steps == 0)
      {
        white_move = 0;
        white_each_interval = 1800000;
      }
      if (white_steps < 0)
      {
        white_move = -1;
      }
      else
      {
        white_move = 1;
      }
      if (white_steps != 0)
      {
        white_each_interval = Hr_interval / abs(white_steps);
      }
    }

    if (currentMillis - White_previousMillis >= white_each_interval)
    {
      white_Secondary = white_Secondary + white_move;
      analogWrite(pwm02, white_Secondary);
      Serial.print("PWM02: "); Serial.println(white_Secondary);

      White_previousMillis = currentMillis;
    }
  }

  while (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    Serial.println("In Input Loop");
    fromAndroid = Serial.readString();
    if (fromAndroid.startsWith("White"))
    {
      fromAndroid.replace("White", "");

      if (fromAndroid.startsWith("time18"))
      {
        fromAndroid.replace("time18", "");
        white_t18 = fromAndroid.toInt();
        Serial.print("white_t18 VALUE: ");
        Serial.println(fromAndroid);
      }
      if (fromAndroid.startsWith("time19"))
      {
        fromAndroid.replace("time19", "");
        white_t19 = fromAndroid.toInt();
        Serial.print("white_t19 VALUE: ");
        Serial.println(fromAndroid);
      }
      if (fromAndroid.startsWith("time20"))
      {
        fromAndroid.replace("time20", "");
        white_t20 = fromAndroid.toInt();
        Serial.print("white_t20 VALUE: ");
        Serial.println(fromAndroid);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code has several `println()` statements for debugging. What's the last line printed, and does it always fail after that particular line?

Comment: what does this mean? `To make the program readable i have only kept the code for few hours.`

Comment: @ jose, ihad kep lot of print statements to find when the code sops, but unfortunately the code doesn't stop at fixed point, it stops at random.

Comment: @jsotola, I had made the program for 24 hours, which had 24 sub If statements, which would be hard to read in a post hence limited the code for couple of hours.

Comment: i think that you only posted code to one hour. please post code for three hours. there may be a way to simplify the code.